# Only 1 item selected in multiselect on postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, drop-down-menu, multi-select

I'm using this [jquery multiselect](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/) control on an asp.net webforms page. Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".multiselect").multiselect();
    });
</script>

<asp:listbox runat="server" CssClass="multiselect">
    <asp:ListItem Value="1">foo</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2">bar</asp:ListItem>
</asp:listbox>

<asp:Button runat="server" Text="save" OnClick="SaveClick"/>
```

My `SaveClick` event is empty, so only a postback is being performed. If I select both items in my multiselect dropdown, and then click submit, only the last item is selected. I found one similar issue [here](https://github.com/ehynds/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/pull/186), but it doesn't seem to apply to asp.net. Anyone figured this one out?

Comment: oh, I'm an idiot. I still need to set `SelectionMode="Multiple"` #facepalm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to set SelectionMode="Multiple"

Comment: I was using a asp:dropdown, which was wrong!  Your example helped me realize the fix.  Thx!